# Bypass OpenVPN Tunnel for Specific Devices (IPs) on Tomato Router Setup

Tags: routing, openvpn, tomato

My setup is pretty straight forward.

```
ISP Modem - 192.168.1.1
    |
Router - 10.0.0.1
  / | \
 Devices
```

I've setup OpenVPN on the router so that all trafic is tunnelled over VPN. I'd like for certain devices to bypass the tunnel but can't seem to figure out what static route setup I need.

I tried this however, it did not work:

```
Destination     Gateway         Subnet Mask         Metric      Interface
10.0.0.4        192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0       0           WAN
```